# KeyStore file is not found in jar, although present in jar

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

I set the [Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html) properties as

```
      LOGGER.debug("ksPath=>" + ksPath);
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystoreFile",ksPath);
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", keyStorePass);
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("sslEnabledProtocols", tlsProtocols);
      httpsConnector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);
      Connector defaultConnector = tomcat.getConnector();
      defaultConnector.setRedirectPort(port);
```

What I see in logs (when it runs)

```
ksPath=>jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore
```

However, the deployment fails and I see logs as

```
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path /shn/lp/jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore due to /shn/lp/jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /shn/lp/jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:413)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:319)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:577)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:462)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:209)
```

**Observation**

```
jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore
```

is different from

```
/shn/lp/jar:file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!my.keystore
```

the latter starts with **/shn/lp/**

However to assert, I see that the file is infact present in jar

```
jar -tvf /shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep my.keystore
  4704 Tue Jun 09 09:29:26 PDT 2015 my.keystore
```

What's up with it?

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: `FileInputStream` doesn't support schemes like `jar:path!entry` or `file:path` or `http:site/resource`, only an **actual file pathname** in the filesystem, either absolute or relative. Your options are (1) modify opensource Tomcat to use an input stream that can read from a jar entry, or (2) put your keystore "file" in an actual file. Depending on your system, you may be able to put the file in a "RAM" filesystem or "temp" filesystem that is not on "disk" (and today "disk" isn't always disk anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Seems it does not understand the protocol, maybe because of the missing leading slash? Have you tried:

```
 String ksPath = this.getClass().getResource("/my.keystore").getFile();
```

Comment: Thanks, now it looks for  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /shn/lp/file:/shn/lp/main-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my.keystore (No such file or directory)
` but still could not find it. Also doesn't this path look weird, Its `HOMEDIR+file:/path/to/jar!my.keystore`?